# How can I display scraped data in Django Template?

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I am trying to display the data from a website by scraping it and storing it and passing it to template but not able to show anything.

[image: pic1]
When a user click on those red button it will scrape the data like ammonium, NO2 etc for that location.

So far I am able to scrape and show the result in terminal but not able to show it on that table.

[image: pic2]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, Http404
from .models import Data,pol
import urllib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request
import os
from django.conf import settings
import csv
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def data(request):
     Am = " ",CO = " ",NO = " ",OZ = " ",SO2 = " ",AT = " "
     PM10 = " ",BE = " ",NO2 = " ", ON = " ", pxy = " "
     TO = " ",BP = " ", PM2_5 = " ",SR = " "
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if 'rowd' in request.POST:
           rowd = request.POST['rowd']         
           station_code = {"av":"QW5hbmRWaWhhcg==","mm":"TWFuZGlybWFyZw==",
           "pb":"UHVuamFiaUJhZ2g=","rkPuram":"UktQdXJhbQ==","airpo":"SUdJ",
           "civilLines":"Q2l2aWxsaW5lcw=="}
           result = None
           #while result:
           sc = {"av":1,"mm":2,
           "pb":3,"rkPuram":4,"airpo":5,
           "civilLines":6}
           while(result is None):
                     print("station",rowd)
                     url = "http://www.dpccairdata.com/dpccairdata/display/AallStationView5MinData.php?stName={}".format(station_code[rowd])

                     html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
                     soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                     regex = re.compile('tdcolor.*')
                     td1 = soup.find_all("tr", {"class" : regex})
                     #td2 = soup.find_all("tr", {"class" : "tdcolor2"})
                     param = ["Ammonia","Carbon Monoxide","Nitrogen Oxide","Ozone","Sulphur Dioxide","Ambient Temperature"," Particulate Matter < 10 µg","Benzene","Nitrogen Dioxide","Oxides of Nitrogen","p-Xylene","Toluene","Barometric Pressure"," Particulate Matter < 2.5 µg","Solar Radiation"]

                     for i in td1:
                         td_list = i.find_all("td")
                         if td_list[0].text in param:

                             val = td_list[3].text.split(" ")[0]
                             if param.index(td_list[0].text) == 0:
                                 Ammonia = val
                                 print("AMMONIA:",val)
                                 Am = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 1:
                                 Carbon_Monoxide = val
                                 print("CO:",val)
                                 CO = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 2:
                                 Nitrogen_Oxide = val
                                 print("NO:",val)
                                 NO = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 3:
                                 Ozone = val
                                 print("OZONE:",val)
                                 OZ = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 4:
                                 Sulphur_Dioxide = val
                                 print("SO2:",val)
                                 SO2 = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 5:
                                 Ambient_Temperature = val
                                 print("AMBIENT TEMP:",val)
                                 AT = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 6:
                                 Particulate_Matter_10 = val
                                 print("PPP10:",val)
                                 PM10 = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 7:
                                 Benzene = val
                                 print("BENZENE:",val)
                                 BE = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 8:
                                 Nitrogen_Dioxide = val
                                 print("NO2:",val)
                                 NO2 = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 9:
                                 Oxides_of_Nitrogen = val
                                 print("ON:",val)
                                 ON = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 10:
                                 p_Xylene = val
                                 print("P_XYLENE:",val)
                                 pxy = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 11:
                                 Toluene = val
                                 print("TOLUENE:",val)
                                 TO = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 12:
                                 Barometric_Pressure = val
                                 print("BAROMETRIC:",val)
                                 BP = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 13:
                                 Particulate_Matter_2 = val
                                 print("PPO2:",val)
                                 PM2_5 = val
                             elif param.index(td_list[0].text) == 14:
                                 Solar_Radiation = val
                                 print("Solar_rad:",val)
                                 SR = val
                     
                     #time.sleep(1000)                    
                     result = 1                  
     context ="Ammonia":Am,"Carbon_Monoxide":CO,"Nitrogen_Oxide":NO,"Ozone":OZ,"Sulphur_Dioxide":SO2,"Ambient_Temperature":AT,"Particulate_Matter_10":PM10          ,"Benzene":BE,"Nitrogen_Dioxide":NO2,"Oxides_of_Nitrogen":ON,"p_Xylene":pxy,"Toluene":TO,"Barometric_Pressure":BP,"Particulate_Matter_2":PM2_5,"Solar_Radiation":SR}
     print(context)
     return render(request,"aqp/template.html",context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()
from aqp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^real_time', views.data, name='data'),
    url(r'^stats', views.stat, name='stat'),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**template.html**

```
<style>
.parent {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;

}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  
}


.filterable {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.filterable .panel-heading .pull-right {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}


</style>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS
  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Optional theme
 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>

function get(clicked_id)
{   var URL = "{% url 'data' %}";
    var data = {'rowd':clicked_id}
    
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){

    });
    
}


</script>

<html lang="en">
{% include "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div class="parent" width="50px">  
<div class=" left ">
<img src="{% static "media/map_delhi.jpg" %}" />
<div id="mm" onclick='get(this.id);' style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;height:20;width:20;left: 295; top:370;"><img src="{% static "media/active.gif" %}" /></div>
<div id="civilLines" onclick='get(this.id);' style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;height:20;width:20;left: 329; top:300;"><img src="{% static "media/active.gif" %}" /></div>
<div id="rkPuram" onclick='get(this.id);' style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;height:20;width:20;left: 265; top:480;"><img src="{% static "media/active.gif"%}" /></div>
<div id="pb" onclick='get(this.id);' style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;height:20;width:20;left: 175; top:315;"><img src="{% static "media/active.gif" %}" /></div>
<div id="av" onclick='get(this.id);' style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;height:20;width:20;left: 465; top:355;"><img src="{% static "media/active.gif" %}" /></div>
<div id="airpo" onclick='get(this.id);' style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;height:20;width:20;left: 155; top:497;"><img src="{% static "media/active.gif"%}" /></div>
</div>
  <div class="right ">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Air Quality</h3>
                <div class="pull-right">

                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filters">
                        
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Parameters" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="concentration" disabled></th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Ammonia</td>
                        <td>{{ Ammonia }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Carbon Monoxide</td>
                        <td>{{ Carbon_Monoxide }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nitrogen Oxide</td>
                        <td>{{ Nitrogen_Oxide }}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ozone</td>
                        <td>{{ Ozone }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sulphur Dioxide</td>
                        <td>{{ Sulphur_Dioxide }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambient Temperature</td>
                        <td>{{ Ambient_Temperature }}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Particulate Matter 10</td>
                        <td>{{ Particulate_Matter_10 }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Benzene</td>
                        <td>{{ Benzene }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nitrogen Dioxide</td>
                        <td>{{ Nitrogen_Dioxide }}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Oxides of Nitrogen</td>
                        <td>{{ Oxides_of_Nitrogen }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>p-Xylene</td>
                        <td>{{ p_Xylene }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Toluene</td>
                        <td>{{ Toluene }}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Barometric Pressure</td>
                        <td>{{ Barometric_Pressure }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Particulate Matter 2</td>
                        <td>{{ Particulate_Matter_2 }}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Solar Radiation</td>
                        <td>{{ Solar_Radiation }}</td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're not doing anything in your javascript with the response, if the call is successful. Also your view should probably just return the data as JSON, not render the template again, so it can be processed by your javascript. Your javascript should just set the contents of the table cell to the data in the response.

Comment: @dirkgroten: Then how to proceed If I am correct this is how we pass the context to the template

Comment: any reference would help.

Comment: what I mean is your view returns an HTML file to your ajax call. But that's not what you want. You want your view to return just the JSON with the values (you could just return `JsonResponse(context)` since `context` is the dictionary with the values). And your ajax to process that an insert the values in the table.

Comment: can't it be done without ajax? sorry for the stupid question I don't know much of web dev, ece student here.

Comment: you are the one using ajax by doing `$.post(...)` and `onclick`. If you replace all your button divs with `<a>` tags with the url embedded, it would just call the view directly and refresh the entire page. That would also work.

Comment: I ain't getting you url means that one I mentioned inside he view right? But how it will be able to show my content?

Comment: using JsonResponse(context) getting this error context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse.

Comment: why isn't context a dict? according to your code, context = {"Ammonia":Am, ...}

Comment: when I do inspect, I can see value displaying under the response tab
https://snag.gy/eRrzHt.jpg

Comment: That’s because you’re returning the HTML table. In that case you can also just replace the table completely in your javascript Ajax success handler. That would also work. For example inside the $.post: `$('.panel-primary).html(response);`

Comment: yes it works but it's show after my that page I get another one with the table having my values

Comment: using ```$('body').html(response); ``` Helped. Thanx for the guidance :)